# 8 Ohm Speaker Gets Hot - Simple 555 Piano

Tags: integrated-circuit, 555, speakers, synthesizer

I have built [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Electronic-Piano/) circuit and nearly everything works fine. I replaced the piezo with a small 8 ohm speaker and put a potentiometer in, so I can control the volume. Unfortunately the speaker gets really hot. What am I doing wrong? Can't I just replace the piezo? Do I have to add something else?

Thanks for helping me

[image]

Comment: Try posting a link to an actual schematic and point out on that schematic where you placed the 8 ohm speaker. BTW, almost certainly it's getting hot because it is taking a large DC current. Piezo's don't do this.

Comment: Did you remember the coupling capacitor, (say 100uF or larger), or are you putting DC across the speaker?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - No, he didn't _forget_ the cap - the circuit as shown doesn't use one.

Comment: Closing since there is no schematic here.  I was going to edit the schematic into this question, so I followed the link.  However, that goes to some page with a bunch of babble and some wiring diagrams, not just a schematic as expected.  There was a schematic further down, that that clearly didn't match the wiring diagrams and pictures.  Then something popped up on that page, and tried to hijack the browser so that going back was difficult. *Screw that!*

Comment: What makes you think you can arbitrarily swap a piezo with a speaker? They are _completely_ different components!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinary 8 ohm speaker has a coil of wire inside, which will get hot if you pass a DC current through it.  The DC resistance is likely to be considerably less than the nominal 8 ohms impedance to AC.  By switching the output between 0V and (approximately) the battery positive, you are - on average - applying a significant voltage across the speaker.

It's normal in such circuits to place an electrolytic capacitor in series with the speaker to block the DC and let through only the AC signal.  Make sure the capacitor is the right way round.

A rough back-of-an-envelope calculation says about 470 microfarad or more for the capacitor.  That gives less than 2 ohms impedance at 200 Hz (and lower still at higher frequencies).  We want the impedance to be significantly less than that of the speaker.  Impedance = 1/(2 π f C), where f is the frequency and C the capacitance.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. How can I determine the value the capacitor should be?

Comment: 100nF is pretty standard for audio input

Comment: @DropArt I've expanded the answer.

Comment: @Makoto - this is an *output*, not an input.  An input has high impedance, so the capacitor can also have high impedance (ie, be of small capacitance).  But an output to a speaker coil is low impedance, so the capacitor must also have a low enough impedance at the lowest frequency of interest to still permit substantial power to reach the speaker - ie, must have much higher capacitance than one used on an input.  Given this is a synthesized source the lowest expected frequency can be known with more certainty than with arbitrary audio.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have seen some other circuits online that do nearly the same as mine. They all use a 10uF capacitor for it. What is correct now? Thanks

Comment: 10 uF will get some audio through but low frequencies will be weak or nearly missing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the lowest tone is ~261 Hz

Comment: You have the information in this answer to run the calculation.  Or you can try it and form a subjective impression, which may actually be what matters most as you'd have to interpret the result of a calculation through a weighted-log model of perceived loudness anyway - and think about the impact of your source's heavy harmonic content.